# Selecting the proper db index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a table with 10+ million tuples in my Postgres database that I will be querying. There are 3 fields, "layer" integer, "time", and "cnt". Many records share the same values for "layer" (distributed from 0 to about 5 or so, heavily concentrated between 0-2). "time" has has relatively unique values, but during queries the values will be manipulated such that some will be duplicates, and then they will be grouped by to account for those duplicates. "cnt" is just used to count.

I am trying to query records from certain layers (WHERE layer = x) between certain times (WHERE time <= y AND time >= z), and I will be using "time" as my GROUP BY field. I currently have 4 indexes, one each on (time), (layer), (time, layer), and (layer, time) and I believe this is too many (I copied this from an template provided by my supervisor).

From what I have read online, fields with relatively unique values, as well as fields that are frequently-searched, are good candidates for indexing. I have also seen that having too many indexes will hinder the performance of my query, which is why I know I need to drop some.

This leads me to believe that the best index choice would be on (time, layer) (I assume a btree is fine because I have not seen reason to use anything else), because while I query slightly more frequently on layer, time better fits the criterion of having more relatively unique values. Or, should I just have 2 indices, 1 on layer and 1 on time?

Also, is an index on (time, layer) any different from (layer, time)? Because that is one of the confusions that led me to have so many indices. The provided template has multiple indices with the same 3 attributes, just arranged in different orders...

Comment: `layer` is redundant when you have a `(layer, time)` index. But the `layer` by itself unlikely to be used anyway due to its low cardinality.

Comment: In your case the `(layer, time)` is the index you need.

Comment: "Also, is an index on (time, layer) any different from (layer, time)?" --- imagine a phone book with `First name, Last name` vs `Last name, First name` and answer your question yourself.

Comment: That's a useful analogy to look at. However, from this logic I can draw 2 conclusions: last name is likely to have higher cardinality than first name, so it would make more sense to search based on last name. However, this implies to me to search by the higher cardinality field, which is time. 

On the other hand, I know that I am searching for certain time values WITHIN a certain layer value, so the order of (layer, time) does make sense in that regard.

Comment: When you search by both fields - the cardinality of the pair matters, not the cardinality of each of its components.

Comment: Ok I guess I have to read up more on that. I'm just wondering, from a simple perspective, can you think of it as having to look up layer first and from there, looking up time, which is why layer precedes time in the index creation?

Comment: Again - return back to a phone book: you need to find every `Last Name = Doe` with `First name` in the range from `A..` to `H..`. What order the phone book must have for you to be capable of searching it quickly?

Comment: Yeah, that's a useful approach. Thank you very much, I'll keep that in consideration in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause appears to be:

```
WHERE layer = x and time <= y AND time >= z
```

For this query, you want an index on `(layer, time)`.  You could include `cnt` in the index so the index covers the query -- that is, all data columns are in the index so the original data pages don't need to be accessed for the data (they may be needed for locking information).

Your original four indexes are redundant, because the single-column indexes are not needed.  The advice to create all four is not good advice.  However, `(layer, time)` and `(time, layer)` are different indexes and under some circumstances, it is a good idea to have both.

Comment: I am actually thinking to exclude (time, layer) because every query involves layer whereas only most involve time. The way the query works is that it will first go into a certain layer (WHERE layer = x) and then, within that layer, find time values within a certain range (time <= y AND time >= z). There is never a case where time supercedes layer, the query always first filters on layer, then filters on time. With this situation, it does seem that (time, layer) would be useless compared to (layer, time)?

Comment: @Ben `WHERE time BETWEEN ... GROUP BY layer`

Comment: Ah, much appreciated for that helpful shortcut